# What's Mandalore's history in Disney's canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon, disney

I want to know what we know about Mandalore in today's canon. I know that Mandalore is shown in The Clone Wars but I don't remember they said anything about the Mandalorian Wars or any other past events. Also, I would like to know the sources.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks to the the canon purge, things like the Mandalorian Wars don't exist anymore within the primary canon.

Comment: @phantom42 According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mandalore/Canon) the Mandalorian Wars are still canon.

Comment: That's why I want to know precisely what's left.

Comment: Please specify if you are looking for information about the planet or the title/role of leader. Both share the name Mandalore, although the leader is called THE Mandalore.

Comment: As @null has pointed out, there's a wealth of information about Mandalore on wookiepedia and elsewhere. There doesn't appear to be a question here, though...